# Creating compiler-enforced rules for .Net projects

Tags: c#

Is there a way to create rules in a C# project that if the user doesn't obey to those rules the project **will not be compile?**

For example, I want to create a rule that the project will not compile unless each interface defined in the project is named with a `T` prefix.

Comment: You can do that with Analyzers that generates errors for things you don't like. There are a ton of built in ones that you can enable or disable and if you have really specific requirements you can make your own. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022

Comment: how complicated is that? do you have an exmple?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix

Comment: is there a way to do it with the linter?
.edirconfig?
I tried but I only got errors but it still compiled

Comment: you can make warnings as errors. most of these will be warning level messages by default

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the built-in naming convention styles of Visual Studio.

[image]

In menu: **Tools** > **Options...**

drill down to: **Text Editor** > **C#** > **Code Style** > **Naming**

Here you can adapt existing rules or create new ones. You will probably find a rule:
<kbd>Interface</kbd> <kbd>Begins with I</kbd> <kbd>Suggestion</kbd>

You can follow these steps to change it.

1. Select <kbd>Error</kbd> from the Severity drop-down (where "Suggestion" is displayed). The compiler will now generate an error, if this naming convention is violated. (Note that you can also choose to generate a Warning instead.)
2. Create a new naming style by clicking on <kbd>Manage naming styles</kbd>.
   Then click <kbd>+</kbd> and enter:

   - Naming Style Title: Begins with T
   - Required Prefix: T
   - Leave the other fields empty and don't change Capitalization which is already set to Pascal Case Name.
   - Then Click OK twice.
3. Now you can replace <kbd>Begins with I</kbd> by <kbd>Begins with T</kbd> in the <kbd>Interface</kbd> rule.

Assuming that you have an interface `public interface IMyInterface { }`, the compiler now generates the error

> IDE1006    Naming rule violation: Missing prefix: 'T'.

Comment: I think someone must have seen "built-in" in the first sentence and thought it only mean static rules, and didn't read enough to realize you could customize them. Or, separately, that its not strong enough because it doesn't explain a way to push and enforce these rules at the team or org level.